# Blinking cursor forever during tailwind install process

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

[Command Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNnME.png)

I am unable to search on SO hence detailing it here, this can be a duplicate question.Refer the Step 4:'Start the Tailwind CLI build process' [TailwindInstallation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) the question is once I run the MSDOS command for CSS processing: npx tailwindcss -i input.css -o output.css --watch , the rebuilding and done is OK with no errors (refer attached command image) but after that my cursor keeps blinking forever, so I cant issue any more DOS commands so then I need to hit CTRL C (say couple of times) to get a message 'Terminate Batch Job(Y/N)' and I choose Y and then its normal command line prompt.This is an irritant.What am I doing wrong , please  advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command ends with `--watch`, so the process will keep running monitoring changes to the files and constantly update the Tailwind css output.

The idea is to leave it running while you are working on the site. If you still need the terminal for something else then open another terminal.

Comment: nice accepted... removing watch solved it